# Even after the state variable is updated using react hooks, the page is not updated/re-rendered

Tags: reactjs

This is where I need my new list of artists to be:

```
<div className="d-flex justify-content-center w-50">
    {addedArtists}
    <div className={`mt-4 mr-2 d-flex ${styles.circle}`}>
       <span className={`m-auto`}>ADD +</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the function called when the follow button is clicked

```
function addArtist(event) {
        addedArtists.push(event.target.value)
        updateArtists(addedArtists);

        ArtistHtml.push(<div key={event.target.value} className={`mt-4 mr-2 d-flex ${styles.circle}`}><span className={`m-auto`}>event.target.value</span></div>)
        updateArtistHtml(ArtistHtml)
}
```

Even after showing that the ArtistHtml state has been updated the html doesn't reflect the change, I even tried doing this

```
{addedArtists.map(item => (
    <div key={item} className={`mt-4 mr-2 d-flex ${styles.circle}`}><span className={`m-auto`}>{item}</span></div>
))}
```

Still no luck, maybe it's some silly mistake. Can someone please help me out here.

Comment: Ciao, do you have a codesandbox in which you reproduced the problem?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough and limited. What is `updateArtists`, what does it do. And doing this `{addedArtists}` in your `jsx` is wrong since it is an array

Comment: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-wiles-pt8n9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) here is the code sandbox, and I just found out that the new divs are rendered when I change the search bar string again

Comment: I found a work around, and I also update the search result in the addArtist() function but I still don't know why the previous thing was not working.